# Python как вставить дату создания файла

Tags: python

У меня есть такая функция.

```
def process_image(file, jpg_quality, png_compress_level, png_depth, png_colors, output_path):
    input_file = str(file)

    if file.suffix.lower() in [".jpg", ".jpeg"]:
        img = compress_image(input_file, jpg_quality, 24, None)
    elif file.suffix.lower() == ".png":
        img = compress_image_png(input_file, png_compress_level, png_depth, png_colors)
    
    if output_path == os.path.dirname(str(file)):
        output_file = os.path.join(output_path, f"compress--{file.stem}{file.suffix.lower()}")
    else:
        output_file = os.path.join(output_path, f"{file.stem}{file.suffix.lower()}")

    if file.suffix.lower() in [".jpg", ".jpeg"]:
        img.save(output_file, "JPEG", quality=jpg_quality)
    elif file.suffix.lower() == ".png":
        img.save(output_file, "PNG", compress_level=png_compress_level)
        
    # Получение времени создания и изменения файла
    creation_time = os.path.getctime(input_file)
    modification_time = os.path.getmtime(input_file)

    # Установка времени создания и изменения для сохраненного файла
    os.utime(output_file, (creation_time, modification_time))
```

Она принимает параметры для оптимизации, и сохраняет с ними картинку с помощью библиотеки Pillow
А после меняет у данной картинки атрибуты создания даты, и изменения на те что были у оригинальной картинки.
Проблема в том что дата-изменения вставляется нормально, но дата создания ни как не хочет вставляться от оригинальной картинке.
Как я могу это исправить, может использовать другу библиотеку, для оптимизации которая имеет тот-же функционал, что Pillow и + может сохранять сразу с изменённым атрибутом?
Или есть другой метод?

Comment: `utime` меняет дату-время **доступа** к файлу и модификации файла, а с датой создания похоже всё сложно и зависит от операционки. Я не знал таких деталей. Для винды вот есть вопрос с ответами https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4996405/how-do-i-change-the-file-creation-date-of-a-windows-file